# Add black border around PDF file with ghostscript

Tags: command-line, pdf, ghostscript

I'm using ghostscript to process some PDF files, and I would like to add a thin black border around the files. Is this something that can be done with ghostscript, or are there other (non-lossy) command-line tools that can do this?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is non-lossy enough for you, but you can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php):

```
convert foo.pdf -bordercolor black -border 10 foo_with_a_10px_border.pdf
```

For a sure-to-be-non-lossy solution, you can build a one-page pdf document with just a border on a **transparent** background and apply it over each page of your document with [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/)'s `stamp` command:

```
pdftk foo.pdf stamp border.pdf output foo_with_my_home-made_border.pdf
```

Comment: Avoid using ImageMagick on a PDF: it would rasterize it.

Answer (score 2):

Typically this can be done by converting the pdf to PostScript, adding to the start a small piece of PostScript code to override the end-of-page function `showpage`, and then printing this, or converting it to pdf.

You can convert to and from pdf with `pdf2ps` and `ps2pdf` which are usually packaged with ghostscript. This example PostScript code adds an A4 sized border:

```
%!PS
% A4 paper is  21.0 × 29.7 cm
/cm { 28.4 mul } bind def
/w 21.0 cm def
/h 29.7 cm def
/border 
{ 0.5 cm setlinewidth newpath
  0 0 moveto w 0 lineto w h lineto 0 h lineto closepath stroke
} bind def
/add-border { gsave initgraphics 0 setgray border grestore } def
/orig-showpage /showpage load def
/showpage { orig-showpage add-border } def
add-border
```

Put this in a file, say `addborder.ps`, then you can

```
pdf2ps a.pdf a.ps
cat addborder.ps a.ps >b.ps
ps2pdf b.ps b.pdf
gv b.pdf
```

For other paper sizes, edit the definition of `/w` and `/h` in centimetres.
The example line width is `0.5 cm` (or half this as the line is centred on the edge of the paper).